# How to upgrade custom 2.79 .py addons to 2.80?

Tags: python, scripting, customization

I have no idea how to upgrade the 2.79 custom shortcuts I´ve done in the past. Currently I have this .py (how can I upgrade it to 2.8?) This is the most essential feature I prominently use when using Blender. Please help.

```
bl_info = {
'name': 'Move origin to selected',
'author': '',
'version': (0, 0, 1),
'blender': (2, 6, 7),
'location': '3d view > space bar > Origin Move to Selected',
'description': 'in edit mode, sets object origin to the median of selected verts/edges/faces',
'wiki_url': '',
'tracker_url': '',
'category': '3D View'}

import bpy

class MoveOrigin(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.origin_to_selected"
    bl_label = "Origin Move To Selected"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        return obj is not None and obj.mode == 'EDIT'

    def execute(self, context):
        saved_location = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location.copy()
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')  
        bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = saved_location

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MoveOrigin)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MoveOrigin)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Have you read these tips on how to update scripts for 2.8? https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API

Comment: I´ll take a look. RNA classes are handle inside the addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated add-on for 2.8 could like the following code:

```
bl_info = {
'name': 'Move origin to selected',
'author': '',
'version': (0, 0, 1),
'blender': (2, 8, 0),
'location': '3D view > F3 > Origin Move to Selected',
'description': 'In edit mode, sets object origin to the median of selected verts/edges/faces',
'wiki_url': '',
'tracker_url': '',
'category': '3D View'
}

import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_origin_to_selected(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.origin_to_selected"
    bl_label = "Origin Move To Selected"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.view_layer.objects.active
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D' and obj is not None and obj.mode == 'EDIT':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def execute(self, context):
        saved_location = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location.copy()
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')  
        bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = saved_location

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_origin_to_selected)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_origin_to_selected)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

API changes include:

- How the active object is accessed
- How to get the cursor location
- Mandatory naming convention for operators

Comment: Thank you so much. Upvoted and answered.